# Regionprops finds always one region - python

Tags: python, image, scikit-learn, scikit-image

I have an image with multiple globs, and when I am using regionprops to find the centroid and BB for each. However, it always finds only 1 for all of them.
More specifically, I get the results on the left image, but I want the one on the right image:
[regions_problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIbuX.png)

My code:

```
            regions = regionprops(itk_label)

            fig, ax = plt.subplots()
            ax.imshow(itk_label, cmap=plt.cm.gray)

            i=0
            for props in regions:
                i=i+1
                print(str(i))
                y0, x0 = props.centroid

                ax.plot(x0, y0, '.r', markersize=5)

                minr, minc, maxr, maxc = props.bbox
                bx = (minc, maxc, maxc, minc, minc)
                by = (minr, minr, maxr, maxr, minr)
                ax.plot(bx, by, '-b', linewidth=1.0)

            ax.axis((0, 600, 600, 0))
            plt.show()
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Funny thing is that the image on the right was also created by me in the past. However, I cannot do it again.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that your features have the same label value. `regionprops` requires that your features are labelled independently, ie. `1, 2, 3, ...`. Here is an example:

In this case both features have label value `1`, so they are measured as if they are one object:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import measure
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

im = np.zeros((600, 600), dtype=int)

im[350:400, 350:400] = 1
im[510:530, 200:240] = 1

np.unique(im)
>>> array([0, 1])

plt.matshow(im)

regions = measure.regionprops(im)
for r in regions:
    plt.plot(*r.centroid[::-1], marker='x', color='r')
```

[image: one feature]

If you use the `measure.label` function you can label the separated features independently, ie. label values `1, 2`:

```
plt.matshow(im)

labelled = measure.label(im)
np.unique(labelled)
>>> array([0, 1, 2])

regions = measure.regionprops(labelled)
for r in regions:
    plt.plot(*r.centroid[::-1], marker='x', color='r')
```

and this gives you your desired result.

[image: labelled]